# Calling nonstatic method on Android from JNI

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I want to call a non-static method on Android using JNI. I can call static methods using  `CallStaticVoidMethod`. To call non-static methods, I have used `CallVoidMethod`. It is not working.

Can anybody please tell me correct code to call nonStatic method of Android From JNI?

```
jmethodID method = env->GetMethodID(gJniRefCached.ImsFwkLoaderClass, "DispVideo", "([BII)V");
```

env->CallVoidMethod(gJniRefCached.ImsFwkLoaderClass, method,arr,width,height);

I have also tried using object of class that code is 
`jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(obj); 
 jmethodID method = env->GetMethodID(cls, "DispVideo", "([BII)V");
env->CallVoidMethod(cls, method,arr,width,height);`

Comment: You should tell us a bit more about what you did. Show us the code that is not working.

Comment: I have pasted the code.. now please help me...

Comment: What is the method signature of the method you're trying to call? Does it return a value?

Comment: no it is not returning anything it is just passing byte Array ie arr and int width and int height of the image to android function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to call an instance method, you need to provide an instance of the class the method belng to, represented as an `jobject`. However, in both examples you are trying to call the instance method with an instance of the class definition, represented as a `jclass`.

Try the following:

```
jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
jmethodID method = env->GetMethodID(cls, "DispVideo", "([BII)V");
env->CallVoidMethod(obj, method, arr, width, height);
```

Note the subtle difference in the third line of code, where I use `obj` as the first parameter, instead of `cls`.

You can see this difference also on the documentation page for the instance method JNI functions: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#wp16656

Look at both `GetMethodID` and `Call<type>Method` - one takes `jclass`, the other takes `jobject`.